# Code after glfwTerminate() never runs

Tags: c++, eclipse, opengl, glfw, glew

I've been trying some modern OpenGL tutorials, and I came across what seems to be strange behaviour. Here is the code, reduced to its (almost) bare essentials.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(){
    std::cout << "Begin program" << std::endl;
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "OpenGL", 0, 0); // Windowed
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    cout << "before glfwTerminate()" << endl;
    glfwTerminate();
    cout << "after glfwTerminate()" << endl; cout.flush();

    std::cout << "End program" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Looking at the [GLFW docs](http://www.glfw.org/docs/3.1/group__init.html#gaaae48c0a18607ea4a4ba951d939f0901), the call to `glfwTerminate()` should not exit the program, but nothing is output to the console after "`before glfwTerminate()`" and the program ends.

I'm on ArchLinux (freshly updated) and I tried with both xfce4 and KDE (minimal install for the latter, just to make sure it wasn't an xfce4 issue).

Would someone have a hint as to what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not finishing the program. Indeed it is processing the lines after `glfwTerminate()`, but somehow glfw is changing how stdout is bound to output stream.

It is a [bug](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/440). You can confirm this by changing `cout` to `cerr`

Comment: Thanks! Looks like they don't intend to fix it. According to that link, the issue is closed.

Comment: No problem, but I disagree with relation to the not intend to fix. For what I understood this issue was fixed by changing  the function `close` to the function `inotify_rm_watch` which remove a glfw instance from watching a file descriptor

Comment: Oh, I see, the fix occured after the latest official release, I should have read more carefully. I might try to compile the libraries myself from the latest available source, then.